# Java clip.play hangs on 3rd invocation

Tags: java, audio

I'm running a java (Netbeans) application on Ubuntu 10.10. The following code plays the sound correctly the first two times it is invoked. On the third invocation, the application hangs and I have to kill the process. Any ideas?

```
try {
        String path = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getAppDirectory();
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("file:"+path+"my.wav");
        java.applet.AudioClip clip = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        clip.play( );
    }catch (java.net.MalformedURLException malex){
        Logger.log(malex);
    }
```

No exception or error is reported.

Comment: are all three invocations opening the same file?

Comment: yes, all three invocations execute exactly the lines of code pasted above. The file and path do not change. FYI, the sound clip is 1.5 seconds long. The invocations may happen roughly 5 to 10 seconds apart.

Comment: @user463994 Run it as a standalone app and when it freezes, run jstack on it:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html  (jstack process-id)

Find the stack trace that contains the invocation of the method that contains the code you pasted.  The stack trace will tell you what method your code is hanging on.

Comment: btw, jstack is in your java/bin directory.  I believe you can also do kill -6 your-application's-process-id (assuming you are on a *nix based system) and it will do the same thing as jstack.

Comment: @mlaw, thanks for the idea. On Ubuntu 10.04 at least, kill -6 pid doesn't produce any extra info. It simply returns to the command prompt. The man page doesn't offer any extra help, afaict. However, your comment gave me the idea to look at strace. I'm reading this now: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace

Comment: @user463994 Try kill -3 then.  Strace may be helpful, but jstack will give you the java stack traces instead of a trace of the native method invocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debugging with strace was getting really complex. I ended up taking the easy way out. Here's my solution:

```
java.io.InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream(path+"my.wav"); 
sun.audio.AudioStream as = new sun.audio.AudioStream(in);
sun.audio.AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

Unfortunately, this is **not** a good solution because: 
warning: sun.audio.AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release.